# Prove continuity of two variable function

Tags: calculus, continuity

Show that the function f is continuous at (0,0) where

$f(x,y) = e^ \frac{-|x-y|}{x^2-2xy+y^2}$, where (x,y)$\not=$(x,x) and f(x,x)=0 using $\epsilon-\delta$ method. I know $e^x$ is continuous but i'm stuck at proving $|e^ \frac{-|x-y|}{x^2-2xy+y^2}| < \epsilon$ whenever $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$.

Comment: are you forced to use $\epsilon-\delta$?

Comment: yes. Ofcourse ϵ−δ definition is required to show continuity and existence of limit

Comment: Why do people down vote a question? Are people afraid of solving such questions? I don't understand what is unclear in this question

Comment: Many people here downvote continuosly by habit!

Comment: what is the purpose or reason behind that habit? Are they afraid of solving the problem or do they want to stop others from witnessing it?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that

$$f(x,y) = e^ \frac{-|x-y|}{x^2-2xy+y^2}=f(x,y) = e^ \frac{-|x-y|}{(x-y)^2}= e^ {-\frac1{|x-y|}}$$

than let $t=|x-y|\to 0^+$ and prove that $e^{-1/t} \to 0$.

Comment: I know this. But how does one prove that there exists  ϵ>0 such that expression <  ϵ whenever 0<|x|<δ and 0<|y|<δ

Comment: @abcdmath But you can simplify a lot by that indeed let consider $t=|x-y| \to 0^+$ then we need to show that $e^{-1/t} \to 0$.

Comment: but how do you prove or obtain the δ condition. If you know the proof, provide complete proof

Comment: fixed $\epsilon$ we need to find $\delta$ such that $e^{-1/t}<\epsilon$ then by log we have $\log (e^{-1/t})<\log \epsilon \implies -\frac1t<\log  \epsilon$, can you finish?

Comment: but how do you find that δ

Comment: Let try from the last inequality, recall that we are looking for $\delta>0$ such that $\forall t$ $0<t<\delta$...

Comment: gimusi, what happens if i take ϵ>e, |x-y|<-lnϵ implies ϵ must be less than e. If i take ϵ>e, |x-y|<-lnϵ gives me contradiction, so the proof is not suitable for every ϵ>0

Comment: We have found that $-1/t<\log \epsilon$ from here we can find the value for $\delta$. It is just an algebraic issue.

Comment: gimusi, ϵ is a distance from the actual value of f(x,y) in either directions. How can it be biased

Comment: also |t|>lnϵ, so how do you prove expr(....)<ϵ condition and arrive at 0<|x|< δ and 0<|y|< δ.  Provide complete solution bro, instead of this lengthy chat. Its getting longer

Comment: You need to fix a value $\epsilon >0$ then from the inequality $-1/t<\log \epsilon$ we can find $t<...$ something depending upon $\epsilon$ then we have found $\delta$.

Comment: edit and prove it completely bro

Comment: Can you find $t$ from here $-1/t<\log \epsilon$?

Comment: why do you choose -1/t < logϵ instead of |-1/t|<logϵ. Its changing and misleading everything here. Its a matter of a minute or two to type or edit  the proof if you've understood it. Why prolong this discussion?

Comment: @abcdmath We are starting from $e^{-1/t}<\epsilon$ form here follow all the step and recall that $t=|x-y|>0$ therefore we don't need absolute value.

Comment: but -1/t is negative. That's what the problem actually is

Comment: What is the problem? $$-1/t<\log \epsilon \iff 1/t>-\log \epsilon=\log \left( \frac1{\epsilon}\right)$$

Comment: @abcdmath It is difficult solve these kind of problem if you have doubts with these basic algebrac manipulation! You should revise that, it is crucial to handle effectivly these kind of inequality.

Comment: @abcdmath Frankly, it seems to me that here your problem is not with the understanding of limit concept but with the related inequalities.

Comment: we need to prove for every ϵ>0 there exists a δ>0 such that |e^|x-y||<ϵwhenever 0<|x|<δ and 0<|y|<δ. If we take |x-y| as t, it reduces to proving  for every ϵ>0 there exits a δ>0 such that |e^(-1/t)|< ϵ 0<|x|<δ and 0<|y|<δ. What made you consider only -1/t<lnϵ when it is actually |-1/t|<lnϵ

Comment: Also provide proof, if you know and are sure about your proof and lets end it. Discussion is looping unnecessarily without any result

Comment: @abcdmath Perfect summary, then using $t=|x-y|>0$ that is $t\to 0^+$ we need to consider $|e^{-1/t}|<\epsilon$. Well, in te latter  $e^{-1/t}>0$ and of course $\epsilon>0$ therefore we can write $e^{-1/t}<\epsilon$ which is equivalent to $\log (e^{-1/t})<\log (\epsilon)$, can you tell why? which is equivalent to $-1/t<\log (\epsilon)$. I don't understand where is the point which is not clear in that derivation.

Comment: @abcdmath Sorry but I don't want give a full solution. I gave all the hints needed and if you need any other advice I'm at disposal. But in nay case let me say friendly that you need to solve that lacking in handle inequalities. Take it as a suggestion!

Comment: so you are saying that it is true for every ϵ>0. What if i take ϵ as e^2, then -1/t<lnϵ implies t<lnϵ which inturn implies |x-y|<-2, which is a contradiction. Did you get my point. I know inequalities well. -lnϵ need not necessarily be negative

Comment: Note that for $\epsilon=e^2$ we have $\log \epsilon =2$ and $-1/t<2$ for any $t>0$ indeed $$-1/t<2 \iff t >-\frac12$$ Anyway here we can assume wlog $\epsilon <1$ since the game is on small value for $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. Therefore we do not need to consider that case.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your time. Its feels nice talking to you. Also, Take a loot at this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2918078/562003

Comment: @abcdmath You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @abcdmath I'll take a look later! Bye

Comment: Bye! Thanks @gimusi

Comment: How to obtain 0<|x|<δ and 0<|y|<δ from -1/t<lnϵ

Comment: @abcdmath We have $$-\frac1t<\ln \epsilon \iff \frac 1t>-ln \epsilon=\ln \frac 1{\epsilon}$$ therefore $$t<\frac1{\ln \frac 1{\epsilon}}$$

Comment: i got up to there. but how to prove |x-y|<f(ϵ) => there exists δ>0 such that  0<|x|<δ and 0<|y|<δ

Comment: Now we now that we need $|x-y|<\delta = \frac1{\ln \frac 1{\epsilon}}$ and you are done indeed it suffices$ |x|<\delta/2$ and $|y|<\delta/2$ that is also $x^2+y^2<\frac{\delta^2}{4}$.